# How to remove gap in between grid rows when manually setting a rows height

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I have the following code:

```
<div class="bg-pink-500 h-[40rem] mt-[0.75rem]">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 pt-[3.125rem] pl-[22rem] pr-[22rem]">
    <div class="col-span-3 col-start-1 col-end-4 bg-slate-400 h-[2rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500">-</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For the first div inside the grid I want to specify a specific height. That row shall be smaller than the next row.

However if i specify both the first and the second rows height it in a big gap between those rows:

[image].

How can i remove that gap?

I tried summing up the heights to pass the required height value to the grid:

```
<div class="bg-pink-500 h-[40rem] mt-[0.75rem]">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 pt-[3.125rem] pl-[22rem] pr-[22rem] h-[17rem]">
    <div class="col-span-3 col-start-1 col-end-4 bg-slate-400 h-[2rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `grid-rows-2` so that the rows are implicit and the content dictates the size of the row.  No more gap.

demo: https://play.tailwindcss.com/kI6jeVywxE

```html
<div class="bg-pink-500 h-[40rem] mt-[0.75rem]">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-2 pt-[3.125rem] pl-[22rem] pr-[22rem] h-[17rem]">
    <div class="col-span-3 col-start-1 col-end-4 bg-slate-400 h-[2rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adjusting the `grid-template-rows` property value to "shrink-wrap" grid row track sizes to the content size:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-pink-500 h-[40rem] mt-[0.75rem]">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-3 grid-rows-[repeat(2,auto)] pt-[3.125rem] pl-[22rem] pr-[22rem]">
    <div class="col-span-3 col-start-1 col-end-4 bg-slate-400 h-[2rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 h-[15rem]">-</div>
    <div class="bg-yellow-500">-</div>
    <div class="bg-green-500">-</div>
  </div>
</div>
```